# How can I refresh variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple php script which connects to a database and gets a variable. The Variable is a integer which counts seconds from 0 to 60.

I can display the Variable, but I need to refresh the page to get the variable refreshed.
Is there a way to refresh variables without a refreshing the page?

Comment: a second is code agnostic, get the initial value, then pass the responsibility of incrementing every second to js, they may go out of sync if you're travelling the speed of light but its relative

Comment: Why are you string a variable, the value of which lives for, at most, a second, in a database?

Comment: Like others said you will need `JS`, as `PHP` is a server-side language; it computes the data before sending it to the client (aka browser) to read and display. So anytime you visit a `PHP` webpage, the `PHP` code has already ran & outputted the data to you.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I'm now trying to do it with Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the php and AJAX to load the variable value in your page and call that function every n time using setInterval() function.

```
function getVariable(){
  $.get(url,function(response){
       //print the value
}

}
and use the setinterval

setInterval(function(){
 getVariable();
},1000); //run every second
```

Comment: To be clear, this isn’t pure JS, it assumes a library is used, maybe jQuery. It might help to reference that for the OP